# Mapping DTO to Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dto

I'm trying to map DTO's to Entities. When I searched it online I noticed lots of references to AutoMapper and just as much feedback about how it is not a good way to do this.

Also I couldn't find any newly dated sources, one question complaining about how there are no "new" sources is 4 years old.

One of the sources I found, which looked really promising was this 
https://rogerjohansson.blog/2013/12/01/why-mapping-dtos-to-entities-using-automapper-and-entityframework-is-horrible/

and I couldnt get it working either.

So, basically situation is like this.

I'm trying to do an integration about orders by using wcf. (A whole another case)

I have an order dto  and related dto's are orderline, customer, customeraddress, orderadress. Some more will follow later.

Since these are essentially database tables, main "table" is Order. It acts as the header, orderline and others are self explanatory. I'm sure everyone came across something like this before.

I created Dto's according to their counterpart entities.

What I'm told to do is;

a) Convert (or as terminology goes, map?) these DTO's to Entities

b) Add the entity to dbcontext and savechanges.

So, can anyone point me in a good direction on solving this situation?

Answer (score 1):

We have a similar project as you. Instead of WCF we use Model classes from MVC, but finally is the same idea: to convert from one object to another. I cannot disagree more about AutoMapper. At first, we had the same doubts about its efficiency, but finally we decided to give it a try. Then, we faced some of the problems the article pointed (especially the collections of elements). Luckily, AutoMapper gives you enough flexibility to handle those special mapping conditions.

- For collections we use custom mappings, which allow us to detect when we have new elements / elements to update / elements to remove
- For references, we follow the rules of Entity Framework: add the FK_Id value rather than the real object.
- If, for some reason, you need to add some logic on the mapping, based on some reference entities, then we use dependencyResolver (only on extreme cases, as we don't like the idea of dependencyResolver)

I think AutoMapper is easy enough to learn the basics, so you can map your objects if a matter of minutes. Plus, it gives you all the tools for the special considerations.

The article you posted explains how "Entity Framework does not like AutoMapper", but its more related on how you follow the rules of EF and AutoMapper. Entity Framework is a huge ORM and, as such, you need to follow some rules (very strict rules in some cases). Of course, using AutoMapper with the basic examples will break some rules, but once you start to get used to it, is really easy to follow the rules.

To sum up: AutoMapper saves you a lot of time, that you can invest on customize some configurations. If not, you will have to use linq projections, which in most cases will take you much more time. For example: the collection problem is solved by detecting the add/edit/delete based on Ids, which can also be handled with AutoMapper through custom mappers.